# What is the right way to write a module finalize method in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to find the right way to use **finalizers** in Julia

Refer to Julia documentation:

> finalizer(x, function)
>
> Register a function f(x) to be called when there are no program-accessible references to x. The behavior of this function is unpredictable if x is of a bits type.

First I genetated a TestModule standard package with a TestModule.jl

```
#in TestModule.jl
module TestModule
end
finalizer(TestModule,(t)->println("fin"))
```

and also a runtest.jl

```
#in runtest.jl
using Base.Test
using TestModule
```

then I tried to test Package but I received ERROR while the test was passed:

```
julia> Pkg.test("TestModule")
INFO: Testing TestModule
jl_uv_writecb() ERROR: bad file descriptor EBADF
jl_uv_writecb() ERROR: bad file descriptor EBADF
jl_uv_writecb() ERROR: bad file descriptor EBADF
jl_uv_writecb() ERROR: bad file descriptor EBADF
jl_uv_writecb() ERROR: bad file descriptor EBADF
jl_uv_writecb() ERROR: bad file descriptor EBADF
jl_uv_writecb() ERROR: bad file descriptor EBADF
jl_uv_writecb() ERROR: bad file descriptor EBADF
jl_uv_writecb() ERROR: bad file descriptor EBADF
jl_uv_writecb() ERROR: bad file descriptor EBADF
INFO: TestModule tests passed
```

after that I arranged another test case

```
julia> workspace() # new workspace
  
julia> typeof(TestModule) # make sure *there are no program-accessible references to `TestModule`*

ERROR: UndefVarError: TestModule not defined

julia> using TestModule

julia> finalize(TestModule)  
fin  # finalize method is working 

julia> typeof(TestModule) 
Module #  make sure *there is program-accessible reference to `TestModule`*

julia> workspace() # force clear references 

julia> typeof(TestModule) # check that *there are no program-accessible references*
ERROR: UndefVarError: TestModule not defined
```

According to above test cases I have some questions

1. Why adding such `finalize` method for `TestModule` generates ERROR during test process?
2. Why `finalize` method was not called while I clear references
3. What is the right way to add `finalize` method for a module

   (OS=Ubuntu , Julia Version=0.4.0)

EDIT

as @Maciek have mentioned, calling `gc()` after `workspace()` also, do not help.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, `workspace` takes no prisoners and in addition the `finalizer` works well only on user-defined and composite types.

I've performed some tests. Have a look at my results:

```
julia> type Foo
         x
         Foo(x) = begin obj = new(x); finalizer(obj,(o) -> println("The end.")); return obj end
       end

julia> Foo(1)

julia> workspace()

julia> gc()
Module the end.error in running finalizer: ErrorException("task switch not allowed from inside gc finalizer")
The end.error in running finalizer: ErrorException("task switch not allowed from inside gc finalizer")
```

Another test with object defined inside module scope:

```
julia> module FinMod

        type T  
            x::Int  
        end

        finalizer(T(1), (t) -> println("Module the end."))
       end
FinMod

julia> FinMod
FinMod

julia> workspace()

julia> gc()
Module the end.error in running finalizer: ErrorException("task switch not allowed from inside gc finalizer")
```

What about functions(first-class objects)?

```
julia> function foo()  println("I'm foo") end
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> finalizer(foo, (f) -> println("foo function is dead now."))

julia> foo
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> workspace()

julia> foo
ERROR: UndefVarError: foo not defined

julia> gc()

julia> #nothing happened
```

So, to summarize: In my opinion `workspace` doesn't call `finalize`. The `finalizer` function works OK only for user-defined and composite types. It does not work for `Module` or `Function`.

Update: I remembered that `workspace` rewrites previous `Main` module into `LastMain`. So even if our module is not accesible from `Main` it's is still alive inside `LastMain` scope (the same works for the function which I used above).